# jquery: obtain select inside a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a table row which looks like [image]

the HTML looks like
[image]

When the user changes the value of the Name field I pass the "select" to nameDropChanged function. After obtaining a reference to select I want to change the value of Number of Coupons select box. How can I obtain a reference to it using Jquery? Also there will  be many such exact rows in the table.

Update : Here is the dummy HTML code and [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pyufe/1/)

```
    <table id="competitors_table" width="100%" style="border-bottom: #000000 solid 1px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:<select name="CompetitorIDs_Setting_[]" onchange="nameDropDownChanged(this);">
            <option value="0">N/A</option><optgroup label="Similar Stores"></optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Other Stores">
            <option value="1">flipkart</option>
            <option value="2">bigshoebazaar</option>
            <option value="160">presto</option>
            <option value="3">fabindia</option>
            <option value="4">fashnvia</option>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="Position_Setting_[]" onchange="dropDownChanged(this);">
                <option value="1000">Top</option>
                <option value="1001">Middle</option>
                <option value="1002">Bottom</option>                                                    
                <option value="">Enter Position</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="PositionNumber_Setting_[]" size="3" style="display: none;">
        </td>
        <td>Number of Coupons:<select id="numberOfCoupons_Setting_[]"></select></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript code

```
  function nameDropDownChanged(select)
{
    var selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;   
    var WebsiteName = select.options[selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var couponCount = <?php if(!empty($couponCount)){ echo json_encode($couponCount); }?>;

    if(Object.keys(couponCount).length > 0)
    {
        var numberOfCoupons = couponCount[WebsiteName];
        var numberOfCouponsDropDown = document.getElementById('numberOfCouponsSelect');
        $("#numberOfCouponsSelect").empty();
        if(numberOfCoupons > 0)
        {
            for(var i=1; i <= numberOfCoupons; i++)
            {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = i;
                option.innerHTML = i;
                numberOfCouponsDropDown.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value=1;
            option.innerHTML = "No Active Coupons";
            numberOfCouponsDropDown.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $('#Selector_ID').change(function(selector){change values in here});

Comment: related HTML code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the nameDropChanged function ..

```
// considering 'parameter' is the variable to be passed as a parameter to nameDropChanged function
$numberSelect = $(parameter).parent().nextAll(':last').children('select');
// $numberSelect is now containing a reference to the numberOfCoupons_Setting_[ select]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

> ```
> $('#Selector_ID1, #Selector_ID2, #Selector_ID3, ...').change(function() {
>     var parent = $(this).parents("tr");
>     var elm = $("td:last-child", parent).children("select");
>     //Do your operation with last Select Element here.
> });
> ```

This helps in two ways

1. You need not to know exact parents and children, but just reverse
   track for parent which is TR in first case and then last SELECT in
   the parent.
2. In a single go you can handle multiple rows. You can
   also use class selector here.